# Communication between Arduinos using USB Host Shield

Tags: serial, usb

I'm working on a project that needs to use USB to pass serial messages between Arduinos (I can't use I2C or SPI for a few reasons – I especially need USB's support for hot-swapping and address allocation). So far I have the USB Host Shield set up on one Arduino Uno, connected to the standard USB port on another. It appears to be working, as can be seen when I run the board_qc:

[image]

The 'slave' Arduino is just running the following code:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hello");
  delay(1000);
}
```

On the master, I create a USB object from the USB Host library (https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0).

```
USB Usb;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Usb.Init();
}

void loop() {
    if (Usb.getUsbTaskState() == USB_STATE_RUNNING)
    {
        Usb.ForEachUsbDevice(&PrintAllData);
    }
} 

void PrintAllData(UsbDevice *pdev)
{
    UsbDeviceAddress adr;
    adr.devAddress = pdev->address.devAddress;
    Serial.println(adr.devAddress, HEX);

    uint8_t msg = 0;
    uint16_t len = 0;
    uint8_t rcode = Usb.inTransfer(adr.devAddress, pdev->epinfo->epAddr, &len, msg);

    if (rcode && rcode != hrNAK) {
     Serial.print(F("\r\nData rcv: "));
     Serial.print(rcode, HEX);
   } else if (len > 0) {
     Serial.print(F("\r\nData Packet: "));
     Serial.print(msg[0]);
   }
}
```

I'm not getting any data through though. Does anyone have any suggestions? Or know of any helpful sample code?

Comment: It would be orders of magnitude simpler and cheaper to use the UART's possibly with a software protocol for addressing and tristating the drivers if you need to connect more than two.  If you really wanted to use USB, you would have to do a lot more than that - you would need to actually implement CDC/ACM protocol or whatever the slave talks, and if it is using a bridge chip, configure the baud rate, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are there any good Arduino libraries you know of for creating a simple USB slave device?

Comment: An ordinary modern Arduino already *is* a simple USB slave device, implementing either a vendor-specific USB serial protocol or a standard CDC/ACM function for the same purpose.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, I'm using Arduino Unos. It looks like the ACM class in the USB Host Shield will help.

Comment: Perhaps, but USB is still just about the worst idea I have ever heard of for communicating between ATmega-based Arduino boards...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, as I said in my question, I need the plug-and-play abilities of USB. I also would like to avoid needing more pins on the Arduino as more devices are connected. Both I2C and SPI don't support auto address allocation, and SPI needs an extra pin per device. This is why I'm trying USB. If you have any better suggestions, it's be great to hear them though.

Comment: No.  USB supports multiple devices *even less* than those two or uarts do - to support multiple devices with USB, you need an additional HUB which is *not* required with the others, and substantial additional software complexity too.  Add unique wiring to any of the others and it is easy to make them support auto-address assignment; but with a little cleverness they can support it *without* that too.

Comment: Can I point out that UART and USB use the *exact* same pins on most boards? In fact, USB is implemented by sending messages from the main chip to the serial chip using UART on most boards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this old abandoned question because it is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of USB and Arduino, and after two years of inactivity the poster seems unlikely to return to either accept an answer or revise their plans to something actually practical.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this lib's documentation? It looks like just doing `init()` and then checking the task state is not enough.

Looking [at the source code](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/Usb.cpp) makes me think you might want to add a call to the main task/state machine, e.g. add a call to `Usb.Task();` to your loop, before your `if` statement.